# How to know application is installed or reinstalled in device

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am doing one application. In that I am using auto renewal subscription. When I install my application, I will do the subscribe operation. And whenever I reinstall the same application in same device, I have to use the restore operation. So how to find application is install or reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

you can store the flag value in keychain according to app is installed or not.

use this link for storing value in keychain

http://dev-metal.blogspot.in/2010/08/howto-use-keychain-in-iphone-sdk-to.html

Also for checking application on device that is install or not use this:

[Detecting programmatically whether an app is installed on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808691/detecting-programmatically-whether-an-app-is-installed-on-iphone)

use this code for saving value

```
- (void) savePassword: (NSString*) password {
[self.keychainItemWrapper setObject:password forKey:
       (id)kSecValueData];
```

}

for retrieve value:

```
- (void) retrievePassword {
return (NSString*) [self.keychainItemWrapper objectForKey:
       (id)kSecValueData];
```

}

Comment: Is this keychain storage is safe?And can i store my information with any key?

Comment: When you need to store data securely from within your iPhone application, sooner or later you will step over the iPhone keychain. This is the super-duper built-in iPhone safe, kindly provided to you by the fruit company. yes you can store value by any key

Comment: If any other application,store the data with same key.Then what i can get when i try to retrieve.

Comment: It will overwrite with new value it's your unique key value you need to take other key value pair for other application

Comment: So Can i store my data with custom key?

Comment: But in that link they given only some of the keys to set the objects.Can you please send me any link for proof for using any key

Comment: you can create and use your own key I have used same things in multiple my apps.

Comment: Should the return type of the `retrievePassword` be `(NSString *)`? Otherwise I think your `return` doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

If any application will write to keychain it's flags to make programmer's life easier, it will   become a trash. Keychain main mission - is to store secure data.

As for subscribtions - use methods, provided by framework to find out whether app has something to restore.For example [MKStore Kit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/)

More useful links:

[link to discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034913/ios-restoring-auto-renewable-subscription)

[link to apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9)